# Why is there a gap between the table and div at the right side?

Tags: html, css, html-table

When I display he following table, there is a gap between the table and div. I'd like to know the reason.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3M45/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table,td {
      border:1px solid black;
      text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div style="width:150px;border:1px solid black;">
      <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td>value
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you mean gap between browser edge and your div in which case the answer below to add `margin & padding : 0` is correct you should edit the question as it is not correct the gap is not between your div and table but browser edge and your div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/Db7Th/

If you don't like how the border is thicker than you possibly want I just removed the border from the div

```
div { width: 150px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Db7Th/1/

Answer (score 4):

Browser apply default `margin` and `padding` to the elements so you need to reset them..

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3M45/2/)

Or you can also use `body`

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3M45/3/)

Note: Am using `*` selector which will apply the properties to all the elements, so if you are looking to target the elements specifically than consider using a `class` or an `id` instead

Answer (score 1):

*"there is a gap between the **table** and **div**"*

It is not between the `table` and `div`, its between `div` and browser frame

You can control it using `margin`. set `margin` to `0`

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```